Combinatorics: Number of Ways of Arranging n People in Circles of Size at least 2
I would like to find a recursive function that counts the number of ways of arranging n people in circles of size of at least 2.
Base cases would be:
f(0)=1
f(1)=0
f(2)=1
f(3)=2
f(4)=9
f(5)=44
f(6)=305 I believe

Given a legal arrangement of n-2 people, we would add 2 people named n-1 and n.

They could form a 2-circle by themselves: 1*f(n-2) possibilities
They could join legal circles: (n-1)(n-2)f(n-2)
They could both join 1-circles: (n-2)(n-3)f(n-4)
Or one could join a 1-circle and the other join a legal circle:
2(n-1)(n-2)f(n-3).
Times 2 since we can switch n-1 and n to be in the 1-circle.

Overall I get:
f(n) = f(n-2) + (n-1)(n-2)f(n-2) + (n-2)(n-3)f(n-4) + 2(n-1)(n-2)f(n-3)
It seems to be close:
f(4) = 9 - correct
f(5) = 50 - more than 44
f(6) = 281 - less than 305

Why do I get this discrepancy and how could I improve my recursive function?

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., here, here, here and here.

Can you elaborate on how you're getting e.g. $(n-1)(n-2)f(n-2)$?

I do not see how you get $f(6)=305$ though perhaps I have misunderstood.

If your $f(4)$ is $\frac{4!}{4!}\frac{(4-1)!}{1!} + \frac{4!}{2!2!}\frac{((2-1)!)^2}{2!}  $ $= 6+3 =9$  then I think $f(6)$ should be
$\frac{6!}{6!}\frac{(6-1)!}{1!} + \frac{6!}{4!2!}\frac{(4-1)!}{1!}\frac{(2-1)!}{1!} + \frac{6!}{3!3!}\frac{((3-1)!)^2}{2!} +\frac{6!}{2!2!2!}\frac{((2-1)!)^3}{3!} $ $=120+90+40+15= 265$

Alternatively you could use $f(n)=\sum\limits_{k=2}^n {n-1 \choose k-1},(k-1)!, f(n-k) $ to represent the possible $k$-person circle the $n$th person is in and the possible $f(n-k)$ other circles, starting with $f(0)=1, f(1)=0$.

@Henry You're right. f(6) = 265 is correct.

Unless I have misunderstood, this is equivalent to the counting of Derangements on $n$ letters.
After all, any permutation is determined by its cycles and requiring that there be no singletons is the same as requiring that you have a derangement.
Indeed, the sequence of derangements, A000166, matches yours up to $n=5$, though the values at $n=6$ differ.  Recursive methods for counting derangements are discussed in the Wiki article I linked to.
May be worth remarking, if you allowed singleton circles then you'd just have the cycle structure for a general permutation, so the answer would be simply $n!$

Permutation cycles (of length >2) have a direction, though. E.g. $(123)\ne(132)$ as permutations but these are the same "circular arrangement" (or aren't they? I guess the problem is unclear).

@Karl i would say they are different circles.  Circles are typically distinct up to rotation.  Reflected circles are different.  I agree the OP isn't clear in the statement,  but this is reflected in the first $5$ values.  I assume the sixth is just an error

To illustrate how I interpret the problem, which may not be what the original poster intended, I am going to first assume that $~n = 11.~$
The first step is to identify each distinct way of partitioning the number $~11~$ into the sum of positive integers, such that each term is greater than or equal to $~2.~$
This can be done as follows:

$11.$

$9,2.$

$8,3.$

$7,4.$

$7,2,2.$

$6,5.$

$6,3,2.$

$5,4,2.$

$5,3,3.$

$4,4,3.$

$4,3,2,2.$

$3,3,3,2.$

$3,2,2,2,2.$


So, the number $~11~$ has $~13~$ such satisfactory partitions.
Superficially, for a specific partition $~x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_r = 11,~$ you might wrongly suppose that the number of ways of forming $~r~$ groups that contain $~x_1, ~x_2, \cdots, x_r~$ people is 
$$\frac{11!}{x_1! \times x_2! \times \cdots \times x_r!}.$$
To understand why this is wrong, consider the following two partitions:
$~\{6,3,2\},~$ and $~\{7,2,2\}.~$
The partition $~\{6,3,2\}~$ can in fact be used to split $~11~$ people into groups of size $~6, ~3, ~$ and $~2~$ in
$~\displaystyle \frac{11!}{6! \times  3! \times 2!}~$ ways.
However, the partition $~\{7,2,2\}~$ can be used to split $~11~$ people into groups of size $~7, ~2, ~$ and $~2~$ in
$~\displaystyle \frac{11!}{7! \times  2! \times 2!} \times \frac{1}{2!}~$ ways.
In the last computation above, the $~\dfrac{1}{2!}~$ factor accommodates that two of the groups are the same size, and further accommodates that (for example) putting Person-1,Person-2 into the first group of size 2, and putting Person-3,Person-4 into the second group of size 2, is the same as putting Person-3,Person-4 into the first group of size 2, and putting Person-1,Person-2 into the second group of size 2.
So, unusual syntax is needed.  That is, for a given partition, you need some way of expressing how many times that each distinct term appears.
I will use the syntax
$$\{x_1:y_1, ~x_2:y_2, \cdots, ~x_r:y_r\},$$
to express that a given positive integer $~n~$ (such as $~n=11$), has been partitioned into distinct terms $~x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_r~$ such that each term $~x_i~$ occurs $~y_i~$ times.
So, for example, the partitions $~6,3,2~$ and $~7,2,2~$ would be written as $~\{6:1,3:1,2:1\},~$ and $~\{7:1,2:2\}.$
Then, the number of ways of forming groups that correspond to the partition $~\{x_1:y_1, ~x_2:y_2, \cdots, ~x_r:y_r\},~$ is
$$\frac{11!}{(x_1!)^{y_1} \times (x_2!)^{y_2} \times \cdots \times (x_r!)^{y_r}} \times \frac{1}{y_1! \times y_2! \times \cdots \times y_r!}. \tag1 $$

Then, once these groups are formed, you then have to determine the number of different ways of arranging each of these groups into a circle.
If a circle has $~m~$ people, then the people may be seated in $~(m - 1)!~$ different ways.
So, for the specific partition $~\{x_1:y_1, ~x_2:y_2, \cdots, ~x_r:y_r\},~$ assuming that you have already chosen which people will go into which of the groups, the number of distinct ways of forming these groups into circles is
$$[ ~(x_1 - 1)!~]^{y_1} \times [ ~(x_2 - 1)!~]^{y_2} \times \cdots  \times [ ~(x_r - 1)!~]^{y_r}. \tag2 $$

So, the overall pattern to computing the general formula for $~n~$ people is clear.
Let $~S(n)~$ denote the complete set of all ways of partitioning $~n~$ into the sum of positive integers, such that each term is greater than or equal to $~2.~$
To clarify,
$$S(11) = \{ ~~\{11:1\}, ~\{9:1,2:1\}, ~\{8:1,3:1\}, ~\{7:1,4:1\}, \\
\{7:1,2:2\}, ~\{6:1,5:1\}, ~\{6:1,3:1,2:1\},\{5:1,4:1,2:1\}, \\
\{5:1,3:2\}, ~\{4:2,3:1\}, ~\{4:1,3:1,2:2\},
~\{3:3,2:1\}, \\
\{3:1,2:4\} ~~\}.$$
For each element $~s \in S(n),~$ of form $~\{x_1:y_1, ~x_2:y_2, \cdots, ~x_r:y_r\},~$ 
define the function
$$f(s) = \prod_{i=1}^r \frac{1}{(x_i!)^{y_i} \times y_i!},$$
define the function
$$g(s) = \prod_{i=1}^r \left[ ~(x_i - 1)! ~\right]^{y_i},$$
and define the function
$$h(s) = f(s) \times g(s) = \prod_{i=1}^r \frac{1}{(x_i)^{y_i} \times y_i!}.$$
Then, the total number of ways of arranging $~n~$ people into circles of size at least $~2~$ is
$$n! \times \sum_{s \in S(n)} h(s). \tag3 $$

I've found the solution to the question:
In a given arrangement of n people, we look at the size of the circle the nth person is in:

Case 1: the nth person is in a 2-circle. Then we choose the other
person in the circle with him: n-1 possibilities, and arrange the
rest of the n-2 people in legal circles.
Overall: (n-1)f(n-2)

Case 2: the nth person is in a 3 or more circle. Then we arrange n-1 people in legal circles, and choose where to place the nth person
(to the right of one of the people). Overall: (n-1)f(n-1)


So the final formula is:
f(n) = (n-1)f(n-1) + (n-1)f(n-2) or f(n) = (n-1)(f(n-1) + f(n-2)), which works perfectly!
And indeed, my f(6) calculation was incorrect, it was supposed to be 265, as Henry pointed out. Which means that my original formula simply was overcounting some of the cases.
